# folder created in my project is not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAt5m.png)

This is my project structure in c#. But in file explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvkUC.png)

the main folder is not seen. Why it not reflecting same

both needs to match. why is it like this how do i create a folder in my solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Folders in your solution explorer are virtual and defined in .sln file. The actual file structure of the solution can be different. It's a little bit counterintuitive, but if you want to see exact same file structure you have to create a solution folder in Visual Studio and then create a real folder in your file system with the same name. Then when you're adding a project to your solution folder you should also select an actual location of the project in your file system.